# Could not load file or assembly "Interop.VBRUN" when using a vb6 ocx control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration, ocx

### Context

I need to create a vb6 *ocx control* and use it in vb.net.
Essentially, it is a collection of methods for drawing on the old vb6 `PictureBox`.

Once the *.ocx* file was created, I recorded it with the usual `regsvr32` procedure and imported it into the Visual Studio toolbox.
I can add the new control to the form without any problems, and it runs.

### Problem

If I add a `button` and in its click sub I call a function of the control (which should, trivially, draw a line on the `picturebox`) an exception is thrown:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.VBRUN, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

### Attempts

- I tried copying all the control code into a new project and exporting the ocx again. *No result.*
- I tried to use the control on Visual Studio 2008 and on Visual Studio 2019 (both on windows XP and on Windows 10). *No result.*
- I tried to comment out most of the ocx control code and leave only a few methods active. *No result.*
- I tried to use the control in a vb6 project. *It works perfectly*.
- I tried trying to import this Interop.VBRUN as a reference, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

#### Notes

I use Vb6 on a virtual machine with *Windows XP*. I've tested the ocx in Visual Studio (2008 and 2019) on this virtual machine and and outside of it (on *Windows 10*). My settings:

- destination Framework = *.NET Framework 4*;
- destination CPU = *x86*

I also searched on *stackoverflow* and around the web for a solution: there are very few similar results, but none with a valid solution.

### Questions

How can I resolve this problem? What is this `Interop.VBRUN`? Is the problem caused by the code (which I should then rewrite) or something else?

Comment: When you say "no result" - what does that mean? I think you meant, those trials made no difference ie the same error resulted?

Comment: `Interop.x` is a managed COM interop assembly for the COM package `x`.  I think it's most likely created automatically by running tlbimp on a type library, so look for it in the output folder for your build.

Comment: Craig's comment is correct. You should look for file 'Interop.VBRUN.dll' and add a reference to it in your project

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs yes: "no result" stands for "this made no difference and the error is still here"

Comment: @Craig in the output folder of my test VS project I have `Interop.<name>.dll` and `AxInterop.<name>.dll` where `<name>` is the name of the created ocx. I can't find any "Interop.VBRUN.dll". I also tried to find this file with the Windows 10 research tool, but it cannot be found on my pc... 
Now I've solved my problem by avoiding the use of this ocx, but the curiosity remains to understand why there is this problem ...

Comment: `AxInterop.` files are created as a .NET "wrapper" for OCX files. `Interop.` files are the same, but for regular DLLs. In general if you had a VB6 DLL `abc.dll` and you referenced that from a .NET project, the file `Interop.abc.dll` would be created automatically, and also added as a reference. This is just FYI; it doesn't explain why the VBRUN file is missing.

Comment: Actually, does your project have VBRUN itself as a reference?

Comment: No... There is no reference to this missing dll.

Comment: VBRUN is the Visual Basic 6 runtime ("Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures"), implemented in MSVBVM60.DLL. You add a reference to this component, and an Interop.VBRUN.dll wrapper will be generated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I used aximp.exe to put a wrapper around a vb6 *.ocx. Maybe give it a try?

Comment: msvbvm60.dll is not an ActiveX control. You use tlbimp.exe to generate a wrapper.